# How do I add multiple tables without writing them 1 by 1

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I try to find small real life problems and attempt to write code to make my life easier,
one of them being a search-table simple program that sorts data based on user input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Tables</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Code</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Description 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Description 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Description 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Description 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Description 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Description 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And my question is, is there a more efficient way to import data rather than having to write.

```
<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Description 6</td>
  </tr>
```

like 1000 times? I would appreciate guidance rather than someone just solving my issue. My aim is to have fun and learn at the same time. Seems though I'm asking google to wrong questions and going down rabbit holes I've no business being in and confusing myself even more.

Thank you for your time reading this and ty in advance on any feedback I may receive :)

Comment: You should normally show us what you already tried and why it doesn't work or match your needs. In this case, you can use a for loop similar to the one you already use to add more `<tr>` with incremented numbers. Try to check each part step by step.

Comment: Ty for the reply , so this is my initial try at making a table like this. What I encountered as a issue that i couldnt solve is what if i have tons of inputs. Would I have to input them manualy 1 by 1? or is there a faster more efficient method to do this? e.g Could i have the data in a .txt file lets say and still present it in a way like what ive done above?  (Just point me in the right direction of what to look at and read , and ill be on my way and happy)

Comment: Well usually data comes from the server, if you use a file it wont be dynamic. If it's just for learning you can go with a json file and do as if it was a server response, you can also try something like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ to have a fake api endpoint

Comment: @LefterisMylonakis: For the tons of inputs, it depends on where they come from. Is it just a list of code from 1 to 100 or is it from an API or is it from a file ? For learning purpose you can just create a for loop that will add a new row with each time a new description with an incremented number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js

```
var dotimes = 1000

 for(i=0;i<dotimes;i++){
    //time to make a list
            const node = document.createElement("li");
    //add it to the body
                document.getElementById("body").appendChild(node)}
```

html

```
<body id="body">
```

Comment: tyvm for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @LefterisMylonakis can can  you mark the question as "accepted answer " please